# JavaScript script reloader

Tags: javascript

Im a little new to HTML programming so I wasn't sure what to do. Im trying to make this script that I have written reload constantly (every second) without refreshing the page. I know that it is supposed to be using the  tag but Im not sure what to put after. Thank you for reading, hopefully someone will help.

Comment: You can use setTimeout to custom reload your content

Comment: I want to refresh the code, but not the page

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean reload without user interaction. You don't need javascript. Place this in `<head>`

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1" />
```

or if you really want to use JS, place this before `</body>` (or before `<head/>` if you're old school).

```
<script>
window.onload=function(){
    setTimeout(function(){location.reload(false)}, 1000);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but this is going to sound  a little embarrassing. I am creating a chat room using :forumlist: tag on wapka. So, I want to make my html code reload without refreshing the page.

Comment: Ok, I don't know what those things are and I'm not sure this is the best way to achieve what you want. There are better ways of replacing content.